# Is there a compiled version of Chrome for the Pi?

Tags: media, google-chrome

I know that there is Chromium, but I am looking for an instance of Chrome that I can install on the Pi.

I want to get Netflix streaming set up on it and it does not work on Chrome.

Comment: The last time I looked, Netflix didn't work on Chrome on Linux, at all... but that has been a while. Has this changed?

Answer (score 2):

No.

Google never distributed Chrome for Raspbian and they [ceased their support](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/m/#!topic/chromium-dev/FoE6sL-p6oU) for 32-bit Linux versions in December 2015.

Comment: So, as it stands, there is no way to view Netflix on the Pi?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=98559